# How can we get port 8080 from adempiere so as to give it dynamically

Tags: sockets, socket.io, adempiere, idempiere

I have a message sending program from server to client which is working inside adempiere. Here I have to give supply port: 8080 dynamically, ie. port must not be hardcoded. Now I am hard coding port 8080 at serversocket and socket

Server

```
    ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(8080, 1, InetAddress.getByName(mSession.getRemote_Addr()));
```

Client

```
    Socket skt = new Socket(ip.getHostAddress(), 8080);
```

Please suggest a method rebel to this hard coding.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The web port is part of the configuration data that is used when the setup process is run but it isn't accessed by the server/client once the setup is complete.  To access the data, you will need to load the configuration data again like this:

```
int webPort = 8080;
ConfigurationData data = new ConfigurationData(null);
if (data.load()) {
    webPort = data.getAppsServerWebPort ();
}

ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(webPort, 1, InetAddress.getByName(mSession.getRemote_Addr()));
```